# Creating an Offline USGS Map Viewer

Tags: web-mapping, mapcache

What steps would I need to take to create an offline 7.5 x 7.5 min USGS Map Viewer similar to this but entirely dependent of an external hard drive for the large data/PDFs? It unfortunately, has to work off an external hard drive because the intent is to give our Search & Rescue folks the ability to print maps on the fly of the desired area when they are deployed across the country for natural disasters. Additionally, it is assumed that connectivity is unlikely for the first several days during a Search & Rescue deployment.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your native map format is going to be USGS 7.5' quads, then the simplest solution is to make up an HTML index page like you show in your question, and have the name of each quad coded as a link to the underlying .pdf map. The user can bring up the index map in the browser and click a quad name which will cause the associated pdf to open in Acrobat Reader (or whatever is the associated pdf app.) Pretty low-maintenance approach.

[edit]

Assuming you have shapefiles or other sources for generating the sort of index page you show in your question, you could use QGIS + QGIS2Web plug-in to generate an offline Leaflet or OpenLayers map. You will have to add a column to your attribute table to map to your pdf files. This attribute column will have to contain HTML code (an HREF, I think), not just the pdf name to make this work. This [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/221893/adding-hyperlinks-to-pop-up-data-in-qgis2web) shows how to do it.

Comment: I am able to create a tile cache of the country through Tilemill and display it into an HTML index page. For displaying the USGS 7.5' quad shapefile into the HTML index page would that require converting the shapefile into GeoJSON format?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the tile cache using [`gdal2tiles`](http://www.gdal.org/gdal2tiles.html) which will take a raster and create a pyramid of tiles ready to load into a Leaflet web map.