# Using QGIS2Web to display pictures?

Tags: qgis, qgis2web, photos, html-popup

I have a problem with displaying an image with QGIS2Web. First, I followed the procedure as given in the link below to pop some images from my photo directory:

[Adding hyperlinks to pop-up data in qgis2web](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/221893/adding-hyperlinks-to-pop-up-data-in-qgis2web)

Then I followed the step and typed like this:

> `CONCAT('<img src = "E:/haris pictures/TL0101.JPG'  width="300" height="225"/>')`

I put that code in my attribute table (FOTO HTML).
[image]

After that, I used QGIS2Web plugin to produce webpage for my map and it doesn’t end up with what I expected, like this:
[image]

Does anyone have suggestions to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using absolute path "E:/haris pictures/TL0101.JPG", where it should be a relative path to the `index.html` file that you are using.

In the link that you are referring: `"../images/Name.JPG"`, the `../images` is the folder name located one level up with the relative to the `index.html` file.

Please note that you forgot also to add another double quote `"` surrounding the path of the images in your question. Also the `img src` tag should not be surrounded by single quote `'`. Here is the correct syntax I am referring from the same link you provided:

```
<img src = "../images/Name.JPG"  width="300" height="225" alt="Alias Name"/>
```

Comment: You were right, but instead of changing the field's Edit widget to Photo in the layer properties, I changed it to Web view. In there you also can control the resolution of the photo. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to do any of this. In your layer in QGIS, create a field for the image, and set its edit widget to "Photo". The images will then automatically be exported for your webmap popups:

https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/wiki/fields,-attributes,-and-popups (last screenshot)

Comment: It also preview an image but I can't control the resolution of the images eventhough I've edit the resoulution in the Layer > Properties > Fields. The pop up images are shown in the original size

Comment: No, the images would have to be at the resolution at which you want to display them. The plugin doesn't resize them. Sorry.