# Image popup Qgis 3.0.3 and qgis2web

Tags: qgis, qgis2web, photos

I want to display an image on the feature popup in qgis2web. I use the latest version of qgis2web and Qgis 3.0.3.

I chose Attachment as the widget type and added the path to the photo using the attribute table. But in the qgis2web export only the path to the photo displays and not the photo itself. It worked in Qgis 2.x using the widget type Photo.

Comment: Have you tried the solution in this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/242733/using-qgis2web-to-display-pictures?rq=1? It was applied using QGIS 2.x.x.

Comment: @gHupf have you found a solution to this?  I've come across many questions with responses for QGIS 2.x but cannot get any of the methods discussed to work with QGIS 3.x