# How can I show pictures from map tips in qgis2web exported maps

Tags: qgis, qgis2web

I have a point layer which pictures. The pictures are stored in my hard drive. In QGIS the map tips and feature attribute form show picture of point perfectly as shown in these 2 prin shots.

[image: Map tip]

[image: Feature attribute form]

Now I want to export this project using qgis2web so that the map shows the pictures just like it does in QGIS. 
What will I have to do??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using QGIS2Web to display pictures?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/242733/using-qgis2web-to-display-pictures)

Comment: Yes I have followed the same process, but the result only show path.

Comment: In that case please update your question with an explanation of what you tried.